# Possible to find and replace in html or asp page on server?

Tags: asp-classic

I wonder if it is possible to find and replace in a .asp (classic) page on the server automitically? 
This is what I want to do: 
In classic asp I copy a folder on my server and paste it in another place on my server(this works as it should), in that folder I have 3 .asp pages and in those pages I want to "find and replace" userId=1 to some other userid that I get from my database.

Is this possible with classic asp or jquery?
Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your question is sightly vague. When your trying to find replace strings, are you looking to literally replace "userId=1" with "userId=X" where X is a value looked up in a database?

If so you are possibly thinking about the problem wrong, instead of trying to find replace files, can't you write a function that communicates with the DB and instead of trying to find/replace in files, then you would just use your function so

```
userId=myfunction()
```

With myFunction returning the ID for the user. That way you don't get into issues with some weird string replacements which you may or may not contextually know what they mean.

If you really want to do find replacements, then I would suggest you write a program that can hook into the `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` functions and watch a directory, then open the file, regex search it for your data and replace the values in. You can find a use of [FileSystemWatercer here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/6ec4b09e-da13-4aea-95db-b3e822fc6b5b/) (Post 3).

Comment: Hi John you are right I want to replace userId=1 with userId=x where x is a value from my db. This is exactly what I want, not just get the value x at runtime.

Comment: Added last paragraph to detail this @ClaesGustavsson

Comment: Thanks, but it seams to big a project, I guess that I have to search some more.

Comment: I'm afraid sometimes the answer isn't the one you were hoping for. The "hackish" way to do this would be to run it on a timer and just search through all files with a Regex... but this would be a very bad idea and become un-managable when file counts explode.

Comment: Yes you cant get everything you want, all the time :-)